# Is it possible to restrict smart contracts to particular users or "hide" the functions (e.g. by encrypting it) after it has been deployed?

Tags: blockchain

Such as by restricting use or views of the smart contract to holders of select public keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After it has been deployed? No. Smart contracts are immutable.

Even before deployment, this can be impossible, or at least hard to do, since all data in Ethereum is public. See a similar discussion [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9175/concealing-sensitive-data-in-a-public-contract).